How to fill the overlap between two arcs?
It is convenient for me to define two arcs as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzfill}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \R{3}
\draw [domain=230:290] plot ({\R*cos(\x)+2.4}, {\R*sin(\x)+\R});
\draw [domain=50:110] plot ({\R*cos(\x)+1.497}, {\R*sin(\x)-2.15761});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The space between the arcs look like a convex lens. How do I use a fill command to fill it? I would prefer a simple implementation.

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.  I marked as a code sample your code, so that it properly formats.  I also made the title a little more descriptive as to the problem in question.  (Nice first question, btw.)

With this code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikzfill}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def \R{3}
        \fill[gray] (290:\R) arc(290:230:\R) arc(290:230:-\R);
        \def \R{5}
        \fill[gray] (290:\R) arc(290:230:\R) arc(290:230:-\R);
%       \draw [domain=230:290] plot ({\R*cos(\x)+2.4}, {\R*sin(\x)+\R});
%       \draw [domain=50:110] plot ({\R*cos(\x)+1.497}, {\R*sin(\x)-2.15761});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

You have:


Thanks a lot, Raffaele. I really appreciate it.

@EugeneVeklerov So you accept  and upvote my answer?
